# Compare two datetime values in a stored procedure using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Inside the stored procedure's `SELECT` statement, I have to get the max datetime value.

```
((SELECT MAX(MyDateTime) 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE MyId = MM.MyId)) as RecentDateTime,
```

This works. I see the new column with the datetime value in the SQL Server Management Studio grid.

However, I need to compare this value with another datetime value to see if they are equal. I get a syntax error for the following statement inside the `SELECT` statement

```
((SELECT MAX(MyDateTime) 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE MyId = MM.MyId) = MM.MyDateTime) as RecentDateTime,
```

Or:

```
@RecentDateTime = ((SELECT MAX(MyDateTime) 
                    FROM MyTable 
                    WHERE MyId = MM.MyId) = MM.MyDateTime)
```

If I can store the result of the comparison to a variable, I can take this value and compare it to another value.

Not sure why I keep getting the syntax error or how to fix this. Any help is appreciated by a newbie.

Comment: Can you show the full `Select` statement?

Comment: do you want your `select` to return a date or the result of the comparison to another date, which would return a boolean (True/False)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
  DECLARE @maxDate DATETIME
  Select @maxDate = MAX(MyDateTime) from MyTable where MyId = testIdValue
```

Now you can compare with anyother date value using `=`, `< >` operators

Comment: you can't use the mxDate column alias in the where clause like that in your second query... if you meant to use the variable @maxDate then I'd question where you got the date `CONVERT(DateTime, '2012-05-31 12:00:00.000')` and why you converted a `datetime` to `datetime`?

Comment: You edit didn't help, since in the top query you are correlating to a table which isn't in a join. i.e. where is mm.MyId coming from? Not being rude, just curious.

Comment: I just copied query from question. I assume this as any value like 1,23 etc

Answer (score 0):

How about a correlated subquery?

```
select 
     t.MyId
    ,t.MyDateTime
    ,RecentDateTime = (select max(t2.MyDateTime) from MyTable t2 where t2.MyId = t.MyId)
from
    MyTable t
```

Or with a derived table...

```
select 
    t.MyId
    ,t.MyDateTime
    ,RecentDateTime = t2.DT
from
    MyTable t
left join
    (select t2.MyId, max(t2.MyDateTime) DT from MyTable t2 group by t2.MyId) t2 on t2.MyId = t.MyId
```

Then, if you wanted only the ones where they didn't match, you could wrap it in a CTE...

```
;with cte as(
    select 
        t.MyId
        ,t.MyDateTime
        ,RecentDateTime = t2.DT
    from
        MyTable t
    left join
        (select t2.MyId, max(t2.MyDateTime) DT from MyTable t2 group by t2.MyId) t2 on t2.MyId = t.MyId)

select * 
from cte
where MyDateTime <> RecentDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're expecting, the other date or the results of the comparison, but if you want only the result of comparing two dates, try:

```
case when (SELECT MAX(MyDateTime)  
          FROM MyTable  
          WHERE MyId = MM.MyId) = MM.MyDateTime 
then 1 else 0 end as isMaxMyDT_eq_myDT
```